# Android Studio's AVD crashes upon launch after IntelHaxm.sys blue screen

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My Android Virtual Device, run by Android Studio 3.3.1 for Windows 64-bit in the Stable version, stopped working after a sudden BSOD caused by IntelHaxm after pressing "Run selected configuration" to test my app.

After the restart, I went on to try to test my app again, but as soon as I pressed the button, some CMD command windows opened again, but this time they were being checked by Avast in real time and after it declared they were inoffensive, they did not launch again and it proceeded to open the emulator as usual.

Now every time I run the emulator, it either crashes instantly or displays the message "Loading state", then it displays another message saying "Resetting for Cold Boot: emulator engine failed" and crashes.

The AVD Images this happened with were Android Pie and Android Nougat, with the latest SDK.

**What I tried**

- Installing a new AVD image and running it.
- Wiping AVD data.
- Cold Booting the AVD (it guarantees an instant crash).
- Deleting and creating a new project.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio and everything that comes with it, same with IntelHaxm.
- Changing the Graphics options to every option possible.
- Updating every driver, every program related.
- Running the AVD standalone.

I've found no related article whatsoever and none of these forementioned solutions have had any positive effect, if any.

**Event Log**

These are the lines of code reporting the error in the console log:

```
10:36 PM    Emulator: qemu_ram_alloc_user_backed: call

10:36 PM    Emulator: (user folder path)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

10:36 PM    Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

10:36 PM    Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(192, 162), size=(300x21), dirty=(300x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null))

10:36 PM    Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(192, 162), size=(300x21), dirty=

10:36 PM    Emulator: (300x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (

10:36 PM    Emulator: null))
```

I'm clueless as to what does it refer to with "A device attached".

**Update**

While writing this post, I ran the emulator several times to reproduce the error. Randomly and suddenly, I got the emulator to run once by running it from the AVD Manager, which surprises me since that didn't work previous times. The emulator didn't contain my app, and when I tried to run it to test my app, through the "Run selected configuration" button in Android Studio's workspace, it crashed as usual.

Comment: Any solution you got to this?  I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Please disable your antivirus when running android emulator or just whitelist the emulator from scanning the emulator. Antivirus program always degrading by making the performance of the emulator slow. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sad to say that it didn't work either :/ I also tried shutting down Avast completely and still nothing. I'm really clueless as to what to do now.